# Installing package "npm install node" fails with E404

Tags: javascript

I am using a Raspberry Pi 4 with "Raspbian Buster with desktop and recommended software".
Version npm: 6.13.4
Version node: v12.16.1

Do anyone know what is wrong?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ npm install node

npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/node-linux-arm - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'node-linux-arm@13.10.1' is not in the npm registry.
```

Comment: did you ever find a solution for this? I'm trying to do the same thing and from my searches, it seems that the package used to determine the node package to install is returning only `arm` as the processor, but there's no `arm` package for node, it should be something like `armv7l`

Answer (score 0):

`npm install node` is not a valid package. Maybe `npm install nodejs`?

You can check all the "package manager" options for node [here](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/), but I didn't see anything related to Raspberry Pi (although I don't know much about Raspberry Pi, so maybe I missed something)

You can always do:

```
npm install npm
```

Which will give you `nodejs` as well. More info [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm).

Comment: Version nodejs: v13.10.1

I did "npm install npm" and "npm install node" again.
Result is the same.

Comment: Hmm I am sorry. I don't know what it could be then :(